# Placeholder animation css is getting hide on key press

Tags: css

I am trying to create floating label similar like in polymer [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input). While typing inside the field, the placeholder is getting hide.

```
.numbrFldCls input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
.numbrFldCls input::-webkit-input-placeholder*[hidden] {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.numbrFldCls input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.numbrFldCls input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -16px, 0);
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will avoid auto hide

```
 input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
              display:block !important;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder text is just that, placeholder text, it will 'disappear' once you start typing. That's what it's supposed to do.

In most cases, you really shouldn't use the placeholder attribute instead of a `<label>` element. They serve different purposes. The label is there to indicate the role of the form element. The placeholder is more of a hint on what kind of information is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the placeholder text in a separate div or a span and align it on top of the input field using margin and change the margin accordingly on focus.

Comment: @ketan This is not related ? Still u have doubt use piece of css code for the placeholder. It will work.

Comment: @RED.Skull So, you should accept any one of the answer. If your problem is solved.

Comment: @ketan. Thanks i found solution on my own.